# In 2016 Theme where is the Posts page thumbnail image stored?

Tags: theme-customizer, theme-options

We built our new site at a staging URL. We then moved it to the live site and everything works fine -except- for the 'Posts' page.

On that page, the image specified as the thumbnail continues to point to the staging URL's img. Like this (see the src attribute):

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
                        <header>
                        <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://staging.example.com/wp-content/uploads/img.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image">
    </div>
```

I tried going into PHPMyAdmin and searching wp_options and wp_postmeta thinking that the URL or image was stored somewhere in those, but I could not find it.

Can someone tell me where this option/value is stored for the theme?

Comment: Only the ID is stored for the post thumbnail image. The URL is based on the URLs in Settings > General.

Comment: Please see my edit. I don't understand your comment. I tried changing the Featured Image on the Page the theme refers to for blog posts and yet the above code is still generated. Where is it coming from?

Comment: That's not what the markup for the post thumbnail looks like in the Twenty Seventeen theme. Twenty Seventeen doesn't even display a featured image on the Posts page. Have you customised it or used a child theme?

Comment: I see you've updated the question to be about Twenty *Sixteen*, but that theme doesn't display the featured image on the Posts page either. So my previous question still applies: Have you customised it or used a child theme?

Comment: To answer your question, we're using a child of 2016. I tried switching to the Vanilla 2016 and it -does- display the featured image in the header of the Page. So that tells me 2 things: 1) There is -something- going on in our child theme and 2) The Vanilla 2016 theme -does- show that featured image. What is weird is that when I go into PHPMyAdmin I see all the GUID and Post_names for the staging site. And yet the vanilla 2016 theme works fine. So confused.

Comment: The GUID has nothing to do with the URLs for posts/pages/media. It is merely a unique identifier for the post and is set to the first URL that was used for it. It is never actually used for generating a URL. If you're using a child theme, you're going to need to share the code you use for outputting the featured image.